# How to get the ID of the conflicting row in upsert?

Tags: postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.5

I have a table `tag` with 2 columns: `id` (uuid) and `name` (text). I now want to insert a new tag into the table, but if the tag already exists, I want to simply get the `id` of the existing record.

I assumed I could just use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` in combination with `RETURNING "id"`:

```
INSERT INTO
    "tag" ("name")
VALUES( 'foo' )
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
RETURNING "id";
```

But this returns an empty result set, if the tag with the name "foo" already exists.

I then changed the query to use a noop `DO UPDATE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO
    "tag" ("name")
VALUES( 'foo' )
ON CONFLICT ("name") DO UPDATE SET "name" = 'foo'
RETURNING "id";
```

This works as intended, but it is somewhat confusing, because I'm just setting the name to the already existing value.

Is this the way to go about this problem or is there a simpler approach I'm missing?

Comment: did you try `returning excluded.id`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That just gives me `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "excluded"` when using `DO NOTHING`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/1411457

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will work (as far as I tested) in all 3 cases, if the to-be-inserted values are all new or all already in the table or a mix:

```
WITH
  val (name) AS
    ( VALUES                          -- rows to be inserted
        ('foo'),
        ('bar'),
        ('zzz')
    ),
  ins AS
    ( INSERT INTO
        tag (name)
      SELECT name FROM val
      ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING
      RETURNING id, name              -- only the inserted ones
    )
SELECT COALESCE(ins.id, tag.id) AS id, 
       val.name
FROM val
  LEFT JOIN ins ON ins.name = val.name
  LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.name = val.name ;
```

There's probably some other ways to do this, perhaps without using the new `ON CONFLICT` syntax.

Answer (score 4):

No idea if how this will perform but just as another option to try, here is doing the same an old-school way (without `ON CONFLICT`):

```
WITH items (name) AS (VALUES ('foo'), ('bar'), ('zzz')),
     added        AS
      (
        INSERT INTO tag (name)

        SELECT name FROM items
        EXCEPT
        SELECT name FROM tag

        RETURNING id
      )
SELECT id FROM added

UNION ALL

SELECT id FROM tag
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM items)
;
```

That is, insert only the [unique] names not found in the `tag` table and return the IDs; combine that with the IDs of the names that do exist in `tag`, for the final output. You can also throw `name` into the output, as [suggested by ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/129591/6965), so that you know which ID matches which name.

Comment: Yes. The last SELECT of my code can also be written as `SELECT .. FROM ins  UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM val JOIN tag ... ;`